# useCollectionOnce infinite loading

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-hooks

I'm using [react-firebase-hooks](https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks) to load data from firestore, and everything is working properly when I use `useDocument` or `useCollection`, but when I try to replace these methods with `useDocumentOnce` or `useCollectionOnce` I got an infinite loading.

useCollectionOnce:

```
const [data, isLoading, isError] = useCollectionOnce( //Infinite loading
   query(
     collection(
       getFirestore(),
       'examplePath'
    ),
     orderBy('test'),
     limit(2)
    ),
    {
       getOptions: {
          source: 'server'
       }
   }
 )

 useEffect(() => {
   console.debug(isLoading) // Output always true
 }, [isLoading])
```

useCollection:

```
 const [data, isLoading, isError] = useCollection( //Working Properly
   query(
     collection(
       getFirestore(),
       'examplePath'
    ),
     orderBy('test'),
     limit(2)
    ),
   }
 )

 useEffect(() => {
   console.debug(isLoading) // Output false after data is retrived
 }, [isLoading])
```

Same thing happen with useDocumentOnce.

**NOTE**
**If a hot reload is triggered, useCollectionOnce loads the data.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

React StrictMode causes the problem. I hope that this answer will help someone.
For more information see https://github.com/CSFrequency/react-firebase-hooks/issues/256#issuecomment-1184750056.